# making a normal video in to audio less video (means the output video should not have any audio in it) by using python

Tags: python

I need to make a normal video into audio less video (means  the output video should not have any audio in it) by using python. Are there libraries or modules to do it. If they are there can you give me an example code for it.

Answer (score 0):

In a linux shell, you can use ffmpeg software like this : `ffmpeg -i "video_file.mp4" -c copy -an "no_sound_video.mp4"`

-an disables audio stream selection (check man of ffmpeg for more info)

You can do it in python calling subprocess :

```
 import subprocess
 command = 'ffmpeg -i "video_file.mp4" -c copy -an "no_sound_video.mp4"'
 subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Maybe you should search for a specific framework ?